# How to copy data from select statement to another database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration

In sql server, I have two servers, each with a database. In the first server (sql server 2005) I wrote select statements which then show data whose column names then match with the tables in the 2nd server (the schema is not the same). This is basically a data migration from 2 servers where the schema is new in the newer server.

But now how can I take the data from the select statement and basically insert that into the new table? Also the new table has auto increment on the ID column, but I want to keep the ID's from the old database because they are used in multiple tables.

Thanks

Comment: You would do this with an insert statement with a linked server. If you need to provide values for an identity column you need to enable IDENTITY_INSERT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward, but has some fiddly bits that most people don't often use.

The simplest way to migrate the data to the new server would be to create a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) using the instructions at this link.

Once you have the linked server configured (and, for this example, I am assuming that you are creating a link on the new server to point to the old server), I would personally make the SELECT queries into Views on the old server.

Then, on the new server, you would create a query sequence like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyNewTable1 ON
INSERT INTO MyNewTable1 [Optional field list here]
SELECT [Field List | *]
FROM MyOldServer.MyOldDB.dbo.MyViewForNewTable1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyNewTable1 OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyNewTable2 ON
INSERT INTO MyNewTable2 [Optional field list here]
SELECT [Field List | *]
FROM MyOldServer.MyOldDB.dbo.MyViewForNewTable2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyNewTable2 OFF

...
```

Et Voila. Your data is transferred, with the same Identity values.

Comment: but its from a sql 2000 to sql 2012. I dont think they support seeing each other?

Comment: Your description up above says SQL 2005. Which is it?

Comment: However, that really doesn't matter. See [this description on how to link SQL 2000 to SQL 2012 and later](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2015/05/15/how-to-create-a-linked-server-to-sql-2000-from-sql-2012-or-later/)

Answer (score 0):

To insert from server A to server B, you need a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

To keep Identity values the same, you need [IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) turned on.